# Flutter xcode sms_advanced plugin eroor : Duplicate interface definition

Tags: flutter, plugins, duplicates, sms, xcode15

I’m new to Flutter 3.13.7 and I’m trying to add the sms_advanced plugin version 1.1.0 to my project, when I run the app using Flutter run I get an error from the Xcode 15 build that says Semantic Issue (Xcode): Duplicate interface definition for class 'SmsAdvancedPlugin', after the error I can’t run the emulator in the project even if I delete the plugin
im using Macbook pro m1 / VScode / iphone 15 pro max emulator
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHRgr.png)

1.I tried to install the plugin using flutter pub get sms_advanced , and tried to install using the dependencies way and flutter pub get

2.Reinstalled Xcode and make sure that the app is updated

3.I tried to delete the duplication in the ms_advanced-Swift.h file
but when i run the app the definition that i just deleted come back .

4.flutter clean / clean build in Xcode and rebuild

5.start new flutter projects

Answer (score 0):

This may be a caching issue when changing dependency versions. I had the same issue when I updated my Podfile (with a different file).

Have you tried deleting the build folder for iOS? This fixed the issue for me.